# Update scope from directive and watch with another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the problem :

I try to do things like this  :

1. Click on a directive triggers an event
2. Event sends data to a rootScope function which sets a scope variable value with new data
3. Another directive has a ng-model in its template which is supposed to reflect the previously changed var
4. Data should be updated in the view AND model. Model is ok (update done), but view update does not seem to trigger automatically, it only updates when I click on the "show button" (see fiddle)

Here is the corresponding jsfiddle I made, with comments :

http://jsfiddle.net/wkmm576m/7/

Here is the code which I think is making trouble... :

```
app.directive('addEditInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        template : '<div id="editForm"><input type="text" ng-model="currentVar.name" /><br/></div>'
    }
});
```

In fact, I return a template, with ng-model. But the ng-model is not updated when its value changes from anywhere else...

Tbh, I'm a bit confused with directives and scopes communications - data....

Thanks for reading / help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - you need to call `$scope.$apply` in top controller:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QEjzlsJj4fh1eeqBXSvt?p=preview

Long answer: you bind usual js function to usual js event, so when user clicks on element - your function executes. Thats all. When you use ng-click - it will trigger digest cycle and your bindings will be updated. So you need to trigger it manually, so you call `$scope.$apply`.

Note: better do not use jquery where you do not need to. I.e. use `$element.bind('click',function(){` instead of `$().on...`

Comment: You are correct with your reason, however it would be better not not manually bind the click at all. The directive uses an isolated scope so there is no problem at all with using a `set` method of it and use `ng-click` on the button in the template to set it instead, negating the need to manually call `$apply`. If it was inheriting the scope then extending it could be troublesome but as its not that's fine. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmm576m/8/

Comment: This is not working. This probably comes from the "isolated controller" I use in my complete project, see this detailed example to see what is exactly going on : http://jsfiddle.net/xmbypv83/

Comment: Click on the "VIEW" in the second column and you will see that the div (directive) supposed to display the currentRow data does not update! (Notice that it has to be two way binded to the globalscope since it should later be edited in the directive's template via inputs)